# Running two commands in crontab

Tags: cron

I have this line in my crontab file

```
*/1 * * * * espeak 'foo' && espeak 'bar'
```

But only half of it, first command gets executed every minute.

While when I write this in the terminal it works like a charm.

Is there a different way to execute 2 commands in the same line in the crontab file ?

Comment: First, use the full path to espeak in crontab. Second use ; rather then &&. `command1; command2`

Answer (score 11):

&& is interpreted by `bash` as one of the operators that separate pipelines in a command line. If you call those commands from `bash` both should run:

```
*/1 * * * * bash -c 'espeak "foo" && espeak "bar"'
```

Comment: From the `crontab(5)` manual, how do you explain that it would be in the manual if it's not going to work?!
`17 * * * *  root  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`

Comment: @AlexisWilke In the example you mention, the crontab starts with `SHELL=/bin/sh` which should be a symlink to a POSIX shell, so it supports `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

Using && in crontab is correct.

If the second command is not executed, it means that the first command does not return successfully. You may then want to use `espeak 'foo'; espeak 'bar'` (so the second command is executed whatever the first one returns), but that does not tell you why the first command does not return successfully.